# If an Infinite language is passed to Machine M, the subsidiary which gives a finite solution to the infinite input tape is?

Tags: automata, automata-theory

```
a) Compiler 
b) Interpreter 
c) Loader and Linkers 
d) None of the mentioned
```

I came across this question while solving mcqs of Theory of Automata. Everywhere the answer is Compiler. But I got no solid explanation for this!! Even the question is itself not so much clear to me. Can someone help?